# .Net 6 config.GetSection() does not act as expected

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get configuration section in .net 6 project, the problem I came across is that `GetSection()` doesn't act as expected, it doesn't return the section, it's just null. Here is some code snippet:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    var e = config["EmailConfig"];
    var s = config.GetSection("EmailConfig:Server");
    IConfigurationSection emailConfigSection = config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name);
    services.Configure<EmailConfig>(emailConfigSection);

    return services;
}
```

`EmailConfig.Name` is a constant and equals to `"EmailConfig"`

variable values look following way `e = null`, `s = "server"` and `emailConfigSection = null`, so what's the reason? Why can't I get full sections

`appsettings.json` if needed:

```
{
 "EmailConfig": {
    "Server": "server",
    "Port": 587,
    "UseSSL": true,
    "Username": "name",
    "Password": "password",
    "DefaultSender": "sender"
  }
}
```

[image: configuration while debugging]

Comment: Why not `config.GetSection("EmailConfig");` ?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg my bad I should have specified, `EmailConfig.Name` is a constant and equals to `"EmailConfig"` so `IConfigurationSection emailConfigSection = config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name);` line does exactly that but it's null

Comment: Do you have a appsettings.Development.json file in your project? Is that changing the value of the EmailConfig section?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, but it's not changing value to null, in fact while debugging I can see the section exists in configuration object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do:

```
var e = config.GetSection("EmailConfig");
```

not

```
var e = config["EmailConfig"];
```

**OR**
Here is a more detailed approach to get the result you are after.

//this gets called at runtime
**Startup.cs**

```
Public Class Startup 
{

   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      _configuration = configuration;
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       //set up config
       services.AddOptions();
       services.Configure<EmailConfig> (_configuration.GetSection("EmailConfig"));
   }

}
```

**We can create a Model to access our config later(EmailConfig)**

```
    public class EmailConfig
    {
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool UseSSL { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string DefaultSender { get; set; }
    }
```

**Getting your config value later on:**
Let's say we need to access the Server

```
Public class TestApi
{
     private readonly EmailConfig _emailConfig
     
     public TestApi(IOptions<EmailConfig) emailConfig)
     {
        _emailConfig = emailConfig.Value
     }

     public string ReturnServer
     {
        var serverName = _emailConfig.Server;
        return serverName;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually lacked `services.AddOptions();` in my startup

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model class defined for EmailConfig, use below code.

```
IConfigurationSection emailConfigSection = config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name).Get<EmailConfig>();
```

else you need to get key value from its property name like below:

```
IConfigurationSection emailConfigSection = config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name);
var server = emailConfigSection["Server"];
var port = emailConfigSection["Port"];
....
```

Comment: What's the reason for `GetChildren`?

Comment: GetChildren: Gets the immediate descendant configuration sub-sections.

Comment: But why do you need to use `GetChildren` when without it you can just plug `config.GetSection("EmailConfig")` into `Configure`?

Comment: it's null regardless, as the parent is null

Comment: @user13490951 what is the value of `EmailConfig.Name`?

Comment: @Manish I updated the description, it's a constant and equals to "EmailConfig"

Comment: @user13490951 I have updated the answer. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @Manish thanks, your answer actually does work but I still don't get how or why, that's interesting cause plain `config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name)` returns null but `config.GetSection(EmailConfig.Name).Get<EmailConfig>();` writes the values to the object without any problem